# When should I use a contains method instead of logical operators in a c# if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, contains, logical-operators

My colleague said I should be using an `array.contains()` in my `if` statements when evaluating enums.

**example a:**

```
if (new[] { enumvalue.a, enumvalue.b, enumvalue.c }.Contains(x.some_enum_value))
{
    do_something();
}
```

...vs **example b**:

```
if (x.some_enum_value == enumvalue.a || x.some_enum_value == enumvalue.b || x.some_enum_value == enumvalue.c) 
{
    do_something();
}
```

When should I use example a over example b?

Comment: Well I think your colleague needs to be hit in the head with a piece of lemon....wrapped around a large gold brick for having a `new` statement **inside** an `if ()` conditional

Comment: I personally would encourage a third option - which is the first one, but storing the data in a `static` field or hashset to avoid the repeated array allocations. Even better, add an extension method to the enum itself so the check has a meaningful name (e.g. `IsEligibleForDiscount`).

Comment: @MickyD LOL you know what that's what I was thinking yesterday after my code was reviewed.

Comment: The advantage, in general terms, of the first option over the second is for **large** numbers of options it becomes less verbose and quicker to read.

Comment: Yeah, I think I disagree with @MickyD here (in terms of the extent of his discomfort). I am not saying I _like_ option A - but it is a not uncommon pattern. And if you value conciseness and readability, it has some nice attributes.

Comment: @mjwills oki.  I've not seen it before, no worries. :)  I wonder if the compiler might optimise it somehow?

Comment: i have an extension method like this:   

public static bool IsContainedIn<T>(this T obj, params T[] args)
{
 return obj != null && args != null && args.Contains(obj);
}

which makes the following:

if (dayOfWeek.IsContainedIn(DOW.Saturday, DOW.Sunday)) .....

Comment: No it won't optimise it AFAIK @MickyD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best of both worlds using *enum constraint* in *C# 7.3*:

```
public static bool IsIn<TEnum>(this TEnum source, params TEnum[] list)
   where TEnum : Enum 
   => list.Contains(source);
```

or if you will:

```
public static bool IsIn<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
   => list.Contains(source);
```

Usage:

```
var someEnum = MyEnum.Three;

if (someEnum.IsIn(MyEnum.One, MyEnum.Three))
{
   Console.WriteLine();
}

var list = new[]
              {
                 MyEnum.Three,
                 MyEnum.One
              };

if (someEnum.IsIn(list))
{
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Note : in short, you should do what you like the most, and what's most maintainable, and also what your boss likes. Everything else is subjective.

Note 2 : The only advantage is the extension method usage, and it can take a list of parameters using the params keyword. Otherwise, there is not much value in this.

Comment: Oooooh _enum constraint_.  _I learnt something new today_ (TM)

Comment: @MickyD Yeah finally we can constrain an enum, its a wonderful time to be alive!

Comment: What benefit does constraining this by `enum` give us? Wouldn't it work the same without any constraint at all?

Comment: @mjwills nothing really, except it just constrains by an enum :) so dirty little fingers dont try pumping other non comparable types in it

Comment: just note that `params` will allocate an array and then copy the values. so consider other options when used in a hot path.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is clear - the **first** approach is **better** because it is more *programmaticaly* and *cleaner*.

Consider you have a lot of item in your collection. So this is not good to put all of them in if statement and write repetitive code which leads to multiline `if` with a lot of or (`||`) statements!

Programmatically means you don't need to write long and hard code every thing. In other words there is a more concise way to do that. Consider another example.You can not to use foreach loop and do it by yourself. But this is not good approach because there is a simlper way and that is to useforeach loop.